# Bootstrap nested columns not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, nested

I am trying to build and design a calculator on a webpage. I am using Bootstrap v4. I am trying to center the calculator using "offset-4", then set the width of the calculator using "col-4". The entire calculator is contained within a div with these classes. Then I want 4 buttons at a time across, each the width of "col-1". However, when I have these nested "col-1" classes, they are significantly shorter than 1 col and, put side by side, they do not fill the width of the calculator. Can anyone help me understand why and how to fix it? Thank you for any help you can offer.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="offset-4 col-4" id="calc">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="title">
      this line will go the full 4 column widths but the buttons below won't
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="screen">
    Calculator screen
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="ops">
    Operations screen
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1" id="ac">
   AC
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="ce">
    CE
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="divide">
    &#247;
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="mult">
    &#215;
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1" id="seven">
   7
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="eight">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="nine">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="minus">
    &minus;
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1" id="four">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="five">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="six">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="plus">
    +
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1" id="one">
   1
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="two">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="three">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="equals">
    =
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-2" id="zero">
   0
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" id="point">
    .
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link to the project on codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/pdVRGb

Comment: Your code from your codepen is different than what you provided. Instead of trying to do an offset-4, try just making a <div class="col-4"></div> before the div. This will add 4 columns that are blank.

Comment: Just forked it. Codepen code is the same as I provided now.

Comment: If I understand correctly- you want the buttons to fill the entire width of the calculator. You would have to change all the col-1 to col-3 for that to happen.